# How to distinguish real price series from simulated series

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption

Given a set of prices, I want to filter out series which are simulated from normal distribution from real prices observed in market. Is there a determining factor between real and simulated price series? I am thinking on the lines of simulated series being closer to normal compared with real series and doing a normality test.

Comment: How it it that you have both real & simulated data, but don't know which is which? Why are you in this situation, & what are you actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

You should be more specific. But yes, definitely, you can check for normality if you are sure that the simulated time series were from a normal distribution and not a more relevant model...

You can check also for other clues as well. And verify the stylized facts.

For stocks, annual volatility should be 30%, for credit in the 60%.
You can check for skewness and kurtosis for a univariate check of the distribution. You can also look for the 'volatility clustering' effect, i.e. volatility is not constant, and during short periods of time can be very high.

For a multivariate check of the distribution, you can verify that the correlation matrix has a hierarchical block diagonal structure, i.e. you have strong groups of correlated time series which are themselves subdivided into even stronger groups of correlated time series.

Cannot help much more without more details.